# Plotting vectors that are not the same length

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series, interpolation

I'm trying to plot two timeseries vectors which aren't the same length:

- `E_Real`  (1x1) double timeseries with 1481409 elements "sampling rate =0,001".
- `E_Guess` (1x1) double timeseries with 384426  elements "sampling rate =0,0059".

MATLAB does not complain about plotting these two vectors and shows the graph below:

[image]

My problem is that the blue line ends before the red one and it doesn't look good (since the vectors do not have the same length). I tried solving this problem using `interp1`:

```
x = 0:0.0059:1481409; % this will make x a Array of Point from 0 to 1481409    
y = interp1(E_Guess.Time,E_Guess.Data,x);
```

Which is supposed to create a new vector `y`, based on `E_Guess` and have the same length as `E_Real`. However, I always get `y=0` without any error message.

What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Do you want both the red and the blue lines to go all the way from the left to the right of the figure?

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you're not using the "x axis" of your data properly.
Take a look at the code below:

```
function q42538517

y = @(x)0.9/1000*x;
x_Real = linspace(0,1481409*0.001,1481409);
E_Real = y(x_Real);

x_Guess = linspace(0,384426*0.0059,384426);
E_Guess = movmean(y(x_Guess) + 0.1*sin(x_Guess/100) + 0.05*randn(1,384426), ...
                  10, 'Endpoints', 'shrink');

% What you're probably doing:
figure();
plot(E_Guess,'b','LineWidth',3); hold on; plot(E_Real,'r','LineWidth',3); 
ylim([0,2.5]);

% What you probably should be doing:
figure();
plot(x_Guess,E_Guess,'b','LineWidth',3); hold on; plot(x_Real,E_Real,'r','LineWidth',3); 
xlim([0 1500]); ylim([0,1.5]);
```

Which results respectively in:

[image]

[image]

Since `E_Real` has a shorter *time extent* than `E_Guess` (`1481409*0.001 < 384426*0.0059`) - there's no need to interpolate the longer one to make it fit the short, just cut the x axis (via `xlim`) as I showed above.